# Can I include a macro in my whole project?

Tags: objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor

I've written a couple of macros which run fine when defined in a header file and included in my .m files.

Is it possible to make these macros available to every .m file without having to include the header every time? For logging and string formatting macros this seems really inconvenient.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing an XCode setting or something but haven't had much luck on Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your macros in project's prefix header (.pch) file.